# use CLLocation to get an address book contact Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, contacts, cllocation, alasset

I have an app in which I get the `CLLocation` latitude and longitude of an image in the camera roll.  I can get the address of those coordinates.  Is there someway to compare that address to the addresses of my contacts and if there is a match create an `NSString` with the name corresponding with that contact address.

//first get the CLLocation

```
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *asset) {
            if (asset == nil) return;
            ALAssetRepresentation *assetRep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
CLLocation *location = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
            NSLog(@"lat;%f",location.coordinate.latitude);
            NSLog(@"long;%f",location.coordinate.longitude);
```

//then find the address

```
CLGeocoder *ceo = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
            CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:location.coordinate.latitude longitude:location.coordinate.longitude]; //insert your coordinates

            [ceo reverseGeocodeLocation:loc
                      completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                          CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                          if (placemark) {

                              NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark);
                              //String to hold address
                              NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
                              NSLog(@"addressDictionary %@", placemark.addressDictionary);

                              NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.region);
                              NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.country);  // Give Country Name
                              NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.locality); // Extract the city name
                              NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.name);
                              NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.ocean);
                              NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.postalCode);
                              NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.subLocality);

                              NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.location);
                              //Print the location to console
                              NSLog(@"I am currently at %@",locatedAt);
}
}];
```

so is there a way to compare this address with the ones in the users contacts to see if there is a match
and then create an `NSString` with the name of that contact

So I have been able to get access to the address book and get the first and last name and the index they reside at.

I have also been able to find out the address entered for each contact, however it is in a form I can't use as I need to make it so I can compare the location of the picture to the location in the address book.

below is my code.  Can anyone help me figure out how to get the address of each contact so I can either
compare the street address and zip code or
convert the address to a set of coordinate that could be compared

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            if (granted) {
                // First time access has been granted, add the contact
                NSLog(@"granted");
            } else {
                // User denied access
                // Display an alert telling user the contact could not be added
                NSLog(@"denied");
            }
        });
    }
    else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        // The user has previously given access, add the contact
        NSLog(@"authorized");
    }
    else {
        // The user has previously denied access
        // Send an alert telling user to change privacy setting in settings app
    }

    CFErrorRef *error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
    //ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    CFIndex numberOfPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) {
        NSLog(@"i;%d",i);

         NSMutableDictionary *dOfPerson=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];


        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );


        NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));

        NSString *lastName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));
         NSLog(@"Name:%@ %@", firstName, lastName);

        ABMutableMultiValueRef address = (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty));

        if(ABMultiValueGetCount(address) > 0) {
            [dOfPerson setObject:(__bridge NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(address, 0) forKey:@"City"];

            NSString *addressste = [dOfPerson valueForKey:@"City"];

        NSLog(@"dOfPerson;%@",[dOfPerson description]);
            NSLog(@"streetadr:%@",addressste);

        }

        NSLog(@"address:%@",address);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out

```
if (picker.sourceType ==UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary) {

    NSURL * movieURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] ;

[self getMediaName:nil url:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]];
    }  


- (void)getMediaName:(UIImage*)originalImage url:(NSURL*)url {
    @try {
        ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *asset) {
            if (asset == nil) return;
            ALAssetRepresentation *assetRep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
```

//I get the asset location

```
            CLLocation *location = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
```

//I break that into the component parts

```
      CLGeocoder *ceo = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
            CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:location.coordinate.latitude longitude:location.coordinate.longitude]; //insert your coordinates
```

//then I reverse location to get a street address and Zip Code and make a string from those

```
            [ceo reverseGeocodeLocation:loc
                      completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                          CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                          if (placemark) {
                              NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark);
                             NSString *strString =placemark.name;
                              NSString *midstring = [strString stringByAppendingString:@","];
                              if (placemark.postalCode == nil) {
                                  postalcodeString = @"00000";
                              }
                              else{
                                  postalcodeString = placemark.postalCode;
                              }

                              combineString = [midstring stringByAppendingString:postalcodeString];
                              NSLog(@"combineString:%@",combineString);
```

//Then I access the user's address book and look for the street address and zip codes of each person and put those together into a string.

```
                              CFErrorRef *error = NULL;
                              ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
                              //ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
                              CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
                              CFIndex numberOfPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

                              for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) {
                                  NSLog(@"i;%d",i);

                                  ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );


                                  NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));

                                  NSString *lastName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));
                                  NSLog(@"Name:%@ %@", firstName, lastName);

                                  ABMutableMultiValueRef address = (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty));

                                  if(ABMultiValueGetCount(address) > 0) {
                                      CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(address, 0);
                                      NSString *streetString = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStreetKey);
                                      NSString *zipString = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressZIPKey);
                                      if (zipString == Nil) {
                                          zipString = @"00000";
                                      }
                                      NSString *interstring = [streetString stringByAppendingString:@","];
                                      NSString *allString = [interstring stringByAppendingString:zipString];
                                      NSLog(@"allstring;%@ %@",allString, combineString);
```

//Then I compare the location string to the address string.  If there is a match I save the name of the person of that address and attach it to the address later to fill in a textview.

```
                                      if ([combineString isEqualToString:allString]) {
                                          NSLog(@"its a match");
                                          NSLog(@"i:%d",i);
                                          firstNameString = firstName;

                                      }

                                      else {

                                      }


                                      NSLog(@"streetString:%@",streetString);
                                      NSLog(@"firstNameString:%@",firstNameString);
                                      NSLog(@"combineString:%@",combineString);
                                                                      }
                              }}
                          else {
                              NSLog(@"Could not locate");
                          }
                      }
             ];
            // Do what you need with the file name here
        };

        ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *error) {

        };

        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [ALAssetsLibrary new];
        [library assetForURL:url resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:failureblock];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

    }
```

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

Get Contacts from address book and compare your address  to contact street address , To get street address from contact book this tutorial may helpful to you

https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-import-contact-address-book/